# tf.keras prediction with a dataset generator

Tags: tensorflow, keras

My tf.dataset is dataset generator. Using it to do predictions with tf.keras predict() I get an output which is multiple times larger than the original input.

I just use a generator of the form

```
 def gen():
    for ex in features:
        d = {k: v for k, v in asdict(ex).items() if v is not None}
        label = d.pop("label")
        yield (d, label)

input_names = ["input_ids"] + tokenizer.model_input_names

dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    gen,
    ({k: tf.int32 for k in input_names}, tf.int64),
    ({k: tf.TensorShape([None]) for k in input_names}, tf.TensorShape([])),)
```

without repeat or anything else.

What is actually outputed of this generator to do predictions? how do I control the size. Why is the output larger than the original size of the dictionary?

How do I properly right using a generator for predictions?

Comment: Please can you share complete code with sample data to replicate your issue?